# Merge 2 arrays in this difficult way in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays **$list** and **$list2**:

**$list**:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [team] => 14
        [team_points] => 3
        [team_occurrences] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [team] => 1
        [team_points] => 3
        [team_occurrences] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [team] => 5
        [team_points] => 1
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [team] => 13
        [team_points] => 1
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [team] => 7
        [team_points] => 0
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [team] => 2
        [team_points] => 0
        [team_occurrences] => 3
    )

 )
```

**$list2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team] => 20
            [team_points] => 7
            [team_occurrences] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team] => 10
            [team_points] => 3
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team] => 14
            [team_points] => 3
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team] => 13
            [team_points] => 3
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [team] => 19
            [team_points] => 3
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [team] => 17
            [team_points] => 1
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [team] => 11
            [team_points] => 0
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [team] => 15
            [team_points] => 0
            [team_occurrences] => 1
        )

)
```

As you can see the columns are the same in both arrays (team, team_points, team_occurrences)

Now, I would like to merge these two arrays into array called **$list_all**

The problem with the merge is that standard merge I have tried

```
array_merge($list,$list2);
```

just add them together.

However, What I need is to count same teams e.g. **[team] => 14** and **[team] => 13** are in both arrays (in $list and $list2) , so, therefore I need to sum **team_points** column value from $list with and **team_points** column value from $list2 if the team is identical. The same for **team_occurrences** column.

So e.g.

New array will not look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array // from $list
    (
        [team] => 14
        [team_points] => 3
        [team_occurrences] => 2
    )

[1] => Array // from $list2
    (
        [team] => 14
        [team_points] => 3
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )

[3] => Array // from $list
    (
        [team] => 13
        [team_points] => 1
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )

[4] => Array // from $list2
    (
        [team] => 13
        [team_points] => 3
        [team_occurrences] => 1
    )
```

But I need that it will look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array 
    (
        [team] => 14
        [team_points] => 6
        [team_occurrences] => 3
    )

[1] => Array 
    (
        [team] => 13
        [team_points] => 4
        [team_occurrences] => 2
    )
```

After the merge I would like to sort the result array using usort() or maybe some better function by team_points DESC (from highest value to the lowest).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you change you`r sql statement?

Comment: No, I need to work with arrays for many reasons :(

Comment: Well...nothing crosses my mind except a for loop...

Comment: Use the team ID as key and implement the code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the first list, creating a new array whose keys are the team numbers.  Then iterating over the second array, if the team already exists, add and otherwise, append.

```
$combined = array();
// First loop creates array keys in $combined array
// based on team numbers
foreach($list as $initial) {
  $combined[$initial['team']] = $initial; 
}

// Second loop looks at $list2 and either adds to values
// if the team key already exists, or just adds the 
// whole subarray on if it doesn't.
foreach($list2 as $secondary) {
  // If it was in the first, append to it.
  if (isset($combined[$secondary['team']])) {
    $combined[$secondary['team']]['team_points'] += $secondary['team_points'];
    $combined[$secondary['team']]['team_occurrences'] += $secondary['team_occurrences'];
  }
  // Otherwise, just add it to the array
  else {
    $combined[$secondary['team']] = $secondary;
  }
}

// Then sort the combined array with usort() into descending order by points
// Anonymous callback function is PHP 5.3+. Needs to be a string value of a named function
// for PHP < 5.3
usort($combined, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['team_points'] === $b['team_points']) {
     return 0;
  }
  else {
     return $a['team_points'] < $b['team_points'] ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

Note: The above produces an output array keyed by team number. If you really just want ascending numeric keys, call `array_values()` on it:

```
// Strip off the team number keys and just use ascending numbers
$combined = array_values($combined);
```

*Edit* Fixed a few missing `]` above...

Comment: What if a team exist in B and not in Initial ??

Comment: @Baba then it just gets added to `$combined`. Do I misunderstand the requirement?

Comment: Yes, then just add. That;s ok. I will try your code and let you know

Comment: @Michael Berkowski to get combine you need to extract it from both array not just from `$initial`

Comment: @Baba It iterates both arrays.

Comment: I have tried your solution but after this code: http://pastebin.com/64rqn5xC I get this result :( http://pastebin.com/3mDccSWW

Comment: @Derfder Post the array definitions into pastebin so I can experiment. I can't see what isn't working (other than a misspelling in team_occurrences)

Comment: @Derfder It's because of a misspelling of the variable `$initial` as `$intial`. I'm typing on a new keyboard and my fingers don't fall where I expect. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/2jVhXg  Always develop with `display_errors` turned on. You would have seen warnings for an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is sorting both arrays on team number (using `usort`). Walk through both arrays at the same time and pick the lowest teamnumber. If list1 is lowest, add that team to the result and increase the list1 index. If list2 is lowest, add that team to the result and increase list2 index. If both teams are the same, combine them by adding the points and occurrences. Repeat until your at the end of one list and add al remaining elements from the other list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
foreach($list2 as $ky => $val) {
    $list2['t'.$val['team']] = $val;
}

$tot = count($list1);
$list3 = array();
for ($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++) {
    $team = $list1[$i]['Team'];
    $list3[]['Team'] = $team;
    $points = isset($list2['t'+$team]) ? $list2['t'+$team]['team_points'] : 0;
    $list3[]['team_points'] = $list1[i]['team_points'] + $points;
    $ocu = isset($list2['t'+$team]) ? $list2['t'+$team]['team_ocurrences'] : 0;
    $list3[]['team_ocurrences'] = $list1[$i]['team_ocurrences'] + $ocu;
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['team_points'] == $b['team_points']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['team_points'] > $b['team_points']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($list3, "cmp");
```

Comment: I gives error Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @Derfder Even if the other answer worked for you and accept it, I still would like to know if my last update did finally work for you too.. :-)

Comment: I corrected misspeling in yur code to team_occurrences but it is still not working. The output of $list3 is empty array like: Array
(
)